# AppFabric DataCacheSessionStoreProvider : some feedback?

Tags: asp.net, session-state, appfabric

Has anyone some feedback on DataCacheSessionStoreProvider included in AppFabric ?
(Performance, Best Practices, Design guidelines, ...)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though i have never use it with AppFabric but I've used NCache session Store Provider.NCache lets you transform your regular ASP.NET sessions into distributed sessions without any code change. You follow a few simple steps and your existing ASP.NET applications can immediately benefit from powerful distributed sessions. please check [This Link](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/ncache-performance-benchmarks.html), it might help you .

Answer (score 1):

Good out of box solution if you want to use AppFabric as your caching system. In our performance tests AppFabric session cache performance is about 2000 requests per second (AppFabric 1.0? only one server without secondary caches). It seems that this WCF service performance limit.